# How refactor this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring, q, restify

I'm little frustrated because I dont know how will I can refactor this script. I write the authenticate function but it's too complicated, maybe too large in one function, and seems a little spagetti :(, how I will be make this a little better? Some clues? Thanks.

```
"use strict";
var errorResponse = require('../errorResponse'),
    paynopain = require('../../core/paynopain'),
    User = require('../../core/User'),
    cache = require('../../core/cache/cache'),
    validateValues = require('../validateValues'),
    API_PATH = 'v1/';


function authenticate(req, res, next) {

    if (req.url.indexOf(API_PATH) !== -1){

        var pnpUserId;
        var validated = validateValues(req, ['pnp_access_token']);
        if(validated.error){
            return next(validated.error);
        }
        var pnpAccessToken = req.params.pnp_access_token;

        cache.read('pnpToken:' + pnpAccessToken)
            .then(function(userId){
                if(userId){
                    storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userId);
                }else{
                    var user = new User(req.logger);
                    return paynopain.getIdFromAccessToken(pnpAccessToken)
                        .then(function(pnpUserIdResult){
                            pnpUserId = pnpUserIdResult;
                            return user.findByPnpID(pnpUserIdResult);
                        })
                        .then(function(userData){

                            if(userData._id){
                                return storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userData._id.toString());
                            }else{
                                var newUser = {
                                    pnpId: pnpUserId,
                                    radius: 1000
                                };
                                return user.create(newUser)
                                    .then(function(userData){
                                        return storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userData._id);
                                    });
                            }

                        });
                }
            })
            .fail(function(e){

                if(e.message === 'invalid_grant'){
                    next(errorResponse.unauthorized());
                }else{
                    req.logger.log('error', 'Error authenticating', {
                        error: {
                            message: e.message,
                            stack: e.stack
                        }
                    });
                    next(errorResponse.internalError());
                }

            });

    }else{
        next();
    }

}

function storeUserIdInRequest(req, next, userId){

    var oneHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
    cache.write('pnpToken:' + req.params.pnp_access_token, userId, {
        expire: oneHour
    })
        .then(function(){
            req.userId = userId;
            req.logger.setExtra({
                userId: userId
            });
            next();
        });

}

function init(server){
    server.use(authenticate);
    require('./configuration/routes')(API_PATH, server);
    require('./products/routes')(API_PATH, server);
    require('./tracking/routes')(API_PATH, server);
    require('./lists/routes')(API_PATH, server);
}
module.exports = init;
```

Comment: If you have working code that you'd like code improvement suggestions on, then you probably want to go to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Possible bug: Shouldn't it be something like `req.url.indexOf(API_PATH) == 0`?

Comment: @Bergi not, because this only its needeit when in the url there are v1 string.But its true that if this string will be at start of url, will be check as you say. Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

It not much better, because i cant see and change behavior of `User`, `cache` and other objects methods, but I hope you can use some ideas from that:

```
"use strict";
var errorResponse = require('../errorResponse'),
    paynopain = require('../../core/paynopain'),
    User = require('../../core/User'),
    cache = require('../../core/cache/cache'),
    validateValues = require('../validateValues'),
    API_PATH = 'v1/';


function authenticate(req, res, next) {
    if (req.url.indexOf(API_PATH) == -1) {
        return next();
    }

    var validated = validateValues(req, ['pnp_access_token']);

    if (validated.error){
        return next(validated.error);
    }

    var pnpAccessToken = req.params.pnp_access_token;

    cache.read('pnpToken:' + pnpAccessToken)
        .then(function(userId){
            if (userId) return userId;

            var user = new User(req.logger);
            return paynopain.getIdFromAccessToken(pnpAccessToken)
                .then(function(pnpUserIdResult){
                    return [ user.findByPnpID(pnpUserIdResult), pnpUserIdResult ];
                })
                .spread(function(userData, pnpUserId){
                    if (userData._id){
                        return userData;
                    }

                    return user.create({
                        pnpId: pnpUserId,
                        radius: 1000
                    });
                }).then(function(user) {
                    return user._id.toString();
                });
        })
        .then(function(userID) {
            return storeUserIdInRequest(req, userId);
        })
        .then(next)
        .fail(function(e){

            if(e.message === 'invalid_grant'){
                next(errorResponse.unauthorized());
            }else{
                req.logger.log('error', 'Error authenticating', {
                    error: {
                        message: e.message,
                        stack: e.stack
                    }
                });
                next(errorResponse.internalError());
            }

        });

}

function storeUserIdInRequest(req, userId){

    var oneHour = 1000 * 60 * 60;
    return cache.write('pnpToken:' + req.params.pnp_access_token, userId, {
        expire: oneHour
    })
    .then(function(){
        req.userId = userId;
        req.logger.setExtra({
            userId: userId
        });
    });

}

function init(server){
    server.use(authenticate);
    require('./configuration/routes')(API_PATH, server);
    require('./products/routes')(API_PATH, server);
    require('./tracking/routes')(API_PATH, server);
    require('./lists/routes')(API_PATH, server);
}
module.exports = init;
```

Note: I cant test it, so I dont know if it realy works fine!

Tips:

- use Q.reject for pass and process errors (especialy in your `User`, and other 'core' object methods)
- not use `else` when in don't realy need
- See ODM\ORM apis ([Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/) \ [Mongoose-q](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-q) is a good sample) to understand how to design clean programming interface